# Find the password!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

The challenge is: `aHR0cDovLzQwNDguY28ubmYv`

Tips: 
**ba(s(2)-s)e 63+1**

To get the password you need to discover what the first line means; the second is **2spooky**.

The password is in the form **Xxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx**

The password has special letters, but just replace them with normal characters, for example: ç = c, ã = a, etc.

Good luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the challenge text is

> base64 encoded from `http://4048.co.nf/`.

Going there gives a page containing the hidden text

> inurl:"141542" intext:"07/10/2008" insrc line 639 in md5 = ise mbu odide foto anya 
> 68747470733a2f2f656e2e77696b6970656469612e6f72672f77696b692f424f41435f466c696768745f373132 
> They're closer than you think.

If you google

> 141542 (because of the inurl prefix)

you'll find

> http://www.al.sp.gov.br/norma/?id=141542, which shows a law passed in 07/10/2008.

Next,

> view the page source and check line 639 (from the insrc prefix above)

and you get the password,

> Sem revogação expressa

Comment: The long string is hex encoded ASCII for: `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BOAC_Flight_712`.  I sense a conspiracy theorist...